# Should I refer to Entity Object class always as DAL or I can use its classes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, s#arp-architecture

Let's say I have 'Customer' table in SQL DB and I'm using Entity Framework.

Now, for instance, in Controller or ViewModel I retrieve the customer by `var customer = Page.Current.Customer` when it's code is:

```
public class Page
{
     ...
     // Customer is EntityObject that created by Entity Framework
     public Customer Customer
     {
        get
        {
                return (new ContextEntity()).Customers.First();
        }
     } 
}
```

**My question:**

Should I refer to Entity Object class(Customer) as DAL and create CustomerWrapper or I can use it in other code of my application?

I mean, is it correct that `Page.Current.Customer` will return **Customer Entity** or I should use **Customer Entity** as DAL and Page.Current.Customer should return custom Customer, some kind of CustomWrapper?

In one hand if will decided to change Customer table name to **site_Customer**(in SQL DB) I'll refresh the EntityModel and will only change the code in the Page class to

```
public class Page
    {
         ...
         // Customer is EntityObject that created by Entity Framework
         public Customer Customer
         {
            get
            {
                    return (new ContextEntity()).site_Customers.First();
            }
         } 
    }
```

But in the other hand I'll have Customer Entity + WrapperCustomer

What is better?

Comment: Why have you tagged this with [s#arp-architecture]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That all depends on the level of abstraction you want to use in your application and needs of presentation layer. Both approaches are possible.

Your code is probably already tightly coupled to Entity Framework (`EntityObject` is EF type) and it is also not very well testable (`Page.Current` is probably static) so discussion about some more advanced architecture approaches and separation of concerns is not needed.

Few observations from your code:

- Context is Disposable!!!
- Renaming anything in your database should not modify your class names. That is the responsibility of EF mapping (EDMX) to correctly map entities to new database names.

Comment: if you mean using IoC, so I changed controller and it takes IProject in its .ctor. Regard 2nd point: but if I used all over my application(Controller, ViewModels, other classes) the **site_Customer** class and tomorrow the table name changed to **t_Customer**, so I'll need to change all **site_Customer** to **t_Customer**. But if I used some kind of CustomerWrapper all over my application, the only change will be `...t_Customers.First<CustomerWrapper>();`

Comment: Changing table name doesn't affect your application only mapping. Your classes and entity sets don't have to use the same name as tables. You can customize names in the entity designer.

Comment: So, I can change table names and then manually map them, right?

Comment: Yes. Once you update model from the database the entity will be still in your model but you must open its mapping details and map it to a new table and its columns.

Answer (score 1):

All class in an EDMX file are partial classes.  This means that you can extend these classes by creating a new Class file.

For example...

```
public partial class Customer
{
    // Here are the methods, properties, relationships created by EDMX Wizard.
}
```

In another area of your project, I usually put it in the same location as the EDMX, you can add a new Class file that has the same signature.

```
public partial class Customer
{
    // Here are the methods, properties, etc. created by you.
}
```

When the project is compiled these two classes will become one class in the compiled code.  Now, when you change your EDMX, yes it should map correctly, but this is not always the case as EF has be known to be very buggy (suppose to be fixed with EF 4.1 in MVC 3), you can simply change the class name to match whatever it is in the EDMX and "Voila!" you have transferred all custom added code for the class to the new entity object.  This is essentially your "class wrapper".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use WCF, then you will probably need to create clear POCOs to avoid a lot of issues.

If you want your controllers/viewmodels/pages/whatever to be unit testable, then you will need to abstract your EntityContext in repository interfaces+classes (see [repository pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)).

If you just want to make a quick and simple non-testable application, then you don't need to bother about it. Don't forget to dispose the data context at the end of each request.